# Editable title of piece (string) on html

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In my piece, I have an string called title. I want to let it editable in the pieces-page, but it seems that there is no posibility of this. I have thought that I could use a rich-text instead of a string, and limit the caracters of it, but I didn't find how to limit the caracters of the rich text.

Is the any posibility to do, one of these options?

Comment: Currently, as you have pointed out, this is not a well-supported use case. We've opened an enhancement issue here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1893

Contributions are of course welcome! You could also sponsor its development through Apostrophe Enterprise Support, or wait for the community or our team to have capacity to pursue it.

Comment: Thanks @TomBoutell, I'm interested in collaborating with this issue. Could you tell me some ideas to approach it and how difficult it could be?

Comment: Hi Kalia, I'm not ignoring the question but I'm not sure how to answer it without getting halfway through the implementation. (: Let me see... something like `apos.inlineField` as a new helper function of both apostrophe-doc-type-manager and apostrophe-widgets would make sense. That would output a schema form inline via apos.schemas and on the front end we'd need code to use apos.schemas.populate and apos.schemas.convert, at intervals since presumably there would be no save button.

Comment: Intervals that would only kick in after some interaction, and attempt to save only when a change appears to be present.